# How to build an object collection from XML using custom model classes?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, mapping, xml-serialization

i have the following `xml` document

```
<class Title="SOCIAL HISTORY" ID="1" ParentID="0">
  <helpNavNode Title="ALCOHOL CONSUMPTION" ID="2" ParentID="1">
    <helpNavNode Title=" Never" ID="3" ParentID="2" Narrative="ALCOHOL CONSUMPTION: Never" />
    <helpNavNode Title=" Occasionally" ID="4" ParentID="2" Narrative="ALCOHOL CONSUMPTION: Occasionally" />
    <helpNavNode Title=" Socially" ID="5" ParentID="2" Narrative="ALCOHOL CONSUMPTION: Socially" />
    <helpNavNode Title=" Daily (3 beers/day) (6 pack/day)" ID="6" ParentID="2" Narrative="ALCOHOL CONSUMPTION: Daily (3 beers/day) (6 pack/day)" />
    <helpNavNode Title=" Is Alcoholic" ID="7" ParentID="2" Narrative="ALCOHOL CONSUMPTION: Is Alcoholic" />
    <helpNavNode Title=" History of Alcoholism" ID="8" ParentID="2" Narrative="ALCOHOL CONSUMPTION: History of Alcoholism" />
    <helpNavNode Title=" None" ID="26" ParentID="2" Narrative="ALCOHOL CONSUMPTION: None" />
    <helpNavNode Title="Alcoholism Screen Question" ID="39" ParentID="2">
      <helpNavNode Title=" Ever had a drinking problem? Last drink? " ID="40" ParentID="39" Narrative="ALCOHOL CONSUMPTION:Alcoholism Screen Question: Ever had a drinking problem? Last drink? " />
    </helpNavNode>
  </helpNavNode>
  <helpNavNode Title="MARITAL STATUS" ID="9" ParentID="1">
    <helpNavNode Title=" Married" ID="10" ParentID="9">
      <helpNavNode Title=" x 10 years" ID="15" ParentID="10" Narrative="MARITAL STATUS: Married: x 10 years" />
    </helpNavNode>
    <helpNavNode Title=" Divorced" ID="11" ParentID="9" Narrative="MARITAL STATUS: Divorced" />
    <helpNavNode Title=" Single" ID="12" ParentID="9" Narrative="MARITAL STATUS: Single" />
  </helpNavNode>
  <helpNavNode Title="Recreational drug use" ID="13" ParentID="1" Narrative=":Recreational drug use" />
  <helpNavNode Title="OCCUPATION" ID="14" ParentID="1">
    <helpNavNode Title=" works for  x 27 years" ID="25" ParentID="14" Narrative="OCCUPATION: works for  x 27 years" />
  </helpNavNode>
  <helpNavNode Title=" 1 child" ID="16" ParentID="1" Narrative=": 1 child" />
  <helpNavNode Title=" 2/3/4/5/6 children" ID="17" ParentID="1" Narrative=": 2/3/4/5/6 children" />
  <helpNavNode Title="Activities" ID="18" ParentID="1">
    <helpNavNode Title=" walks regularly" ID="19" ParentID="18" Narrative="Activities: walks regularly" />
    <helpNavNode Title=" cycles for exercise" ID="20" ParentID="18" Narrative="Activities: cycles for exercise" />
    <helpNavNode Title=" runs 3 days/week" ID="21" ParentID="18" Narrative="Activities: runs 3 days/week" />
    <helpNavNode Title=" hunting and fishing" ID="22" ParentID="18" Narrative="Activities: hunting and fishing" />
    <helpNavNode Title=" hiking and camping" ID="23" ParentID="18" Narrative="Activities: hiking and camping" />
    <helpNavNode Title=" swims regularly" ID="24" ParentID="18" Narrative="Activities: swims regularly" />
  </helpNavNode>
  <helpNavNode Title="Tobacco Use" ID="27" ParentID="1">
    <helpNavNode Title="Cigar, Cigarette, Pipe, Smokeless" ID="30" ParentID="27">
      <helpNavNode Title="10/pk year" ID="32" ParentID="30" Narrative="Tobacco Use:Cigar, Cigarette, Pipe, Smokeless:10/pk year" />
    </helpNavNode>
    <helpNavNode Title="Quit Date" ID="35" ParentID="27" Narrative="Tobacco Use:Quit Date" />
    <helpNavNode Title="Year Started" ID="36" ParentID="27" Narrative="Tobacco Use:Year Started" />
  </helpNavNode>
  <helpNavNode Title="SocHx  Template" ID="37" ParentID="1">
    <helpNavNode Title=" Living situation:  Occupation:  Tobacco:  EtOH:  Rec. drugs: " ID="41" ParentID="37" Narrative="SocHx  Template: Living situation:  Occupation:  Tobacco:  EtOH:  Rec. drugs: " />
    <helpNavNode Title=" Living situation:  Occupation:  Tobacco:  EtOH:  Rec. drugs: " ID="42" ParentID="37" Narrative="SocHx  Template: Living situation:  Occupation:  Tobacco:  EtOH:  Rec. drugs: " />
  </helpNavNode>
</class>
```

i need to map this document in to a class

```
public class @class
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string text { get; set; }
    public string parent { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }

    public List<helpNavNode> nodes { get; set; }

    public @class()
    {
        nodes = new List<helpNavNode>();
    }
}

    public class helpNavNode
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string text { get; set; }
        public string parent { get; set; }
        public string value { get; set; }
    }
```

i have added `id,text,parent,value` becuase both the parent node `"class"` and child node `"helpNavNode"` has common attributes.

The attributes `Title, ID, ParentID` of the node `'class'` must map to `text, id, parent` in the `@class` and `Title, ID, ParentID, narrative` of nodes `"helpNavNode"` must map to `text, id, parent, value` of the `"helpNavNode"` class. Thus how to create the object collection of `"@class"` and `"helNavNode"`?

Comment: A good start is to read about Linq to XML: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx You can use this framework to read the XML and deserialize it into classes.

Answer (score 0):

I pefere not to write custom serializators. So i recomment you to create class that will easy desirialize yor structire. Here it is:

```
/// <remarks/>
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
public partial class @class
{

    private classHelpNavNode[] helpNavNodeField;

    private string titleField;

    private byte idField;

    private byte parentIDField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("helpNavNode")]
    public classHelpNavNode[] helpNavNode
    {
        get
        {
            return this.helpNavNodeField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.helpNavNodeField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string Title
    {
        get
        {
            return this.titleField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.titleField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public byte ID
    {
        get
        {
            return this.idField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.idField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public byte ParentID
    {
        get
        {
            return this.parentIDField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.parentIDField = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
public partial class classHelpNavNode
{

    private classHelpNavNode[] helpNavNodeField;

    private string titleField;

    private byte idField;

    private byte parentIDField;

    private string narrativeField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("helpNavNode")]
    public classHelpNavNode[] helpNavNode
    {
        get
        {
            return this.helpNavNodeField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.helpNavNodeField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string Title
    {
        get
        {
            return this.titleField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.titleField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public byte ID
    {
        get
        {
            return this.idField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.idField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public byte ParentID
    {
        get
        {
            return this.parentIDField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.parentIDField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string Narrative
    {
        get
        {
            return this.narrativeField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.narrativeField = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can easily deserialize your xml to object:

```
@class data = null;
string path = @"D:\test.xml"; //Your xml path

XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(@class));

using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(path))
{
    data = (@class)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
}
```

Now, since you have your data in `data` object. It's really easy to map data to your stucture. You even cat use something like [**AutoMapper**](http://automapper.org/).

Comment: but i dont want the class to have the same properties as XML eg: Title property must be replaced by text (lower case 'text') the point it the Title must mapped to 'text' and so on wards

Comment: I get it. But i recommend you just transform this data to yours by mapping not by custom serialization